# Use sites theme colour for new answer banner

Tags: feature-request, design

I got greeted by this orange banner when I opened my phone again, since I started to answer on my phone but posted it from my computer. Can we please use a colour from a site's theme for the background of this banner, this SO orange looks really hideous when combined with the MSE theme.

[image: Screenshot showing a bright orange banner that reads: "1 new answer has been posted - load new answers"]